# What is the minimal polynomial of $x$ over $k(x^p - x)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, minimal-polynomials

Let $k=\Bbb F_p$, and let $k(x)$ be the rational function field in one variable over $k$. Define $\phi:k(x)\to k(x)$ by $\phi(x)=x+1$. I know that $\phi$ has order $p$ in $\operatorname{Gal}(k(x)/k)$ and $k(x^p-x)$ is the fixed field of $\phi$, but I'm confused about the minimal polynomial of $x$ over $k(x^p-x)$. (This is problem 17 of *Fields and Galois Theory* by Patrick Morandi, page 27.)
Please explain about that minimal polynomial or calculate it!

Comment: Do you have a guess?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg: I have problem in meaning of minimal polynomial  but I guess $x^{p-1}-1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have absolutely no idea to get the minimal polynomial, and you know that there is an isomorphism $\Bbb F_p \to Gal(k(x)/k(x^p-x))$ given by $t \mapsto (x \mapsto x+t)$, then you know that the conjugates of $x$ are the $x+t$, and then you can simply compute the product $\prod_{t \in \Bbb F_p}(T-(x+t))$. This product is invariant by $x \mapsto x+1$ so its coefficients will be in $k(x^p-x)$.

You will find $\prod_{t \in \Bbb F_p}(T-(x+t)) = \prod_{t \in \Bbb F_p}((T-x)-t) = (T-x)^p - (T-x) = (T^p-T)-(x^p-x)$

This is a polynomial $P(T)$ with coefficients in $k(x^p-x)$, and $P(x)=0$.

More generally, if you consider the extension $k(f(x)) \subset k(x)$ with $f(x) = P(x)/Q(x)$, then $Q(T)f(x)-P(T)$ is an obvious polynomial over $k(f(x))$ annihilating $x$

Answer (score 3):

The hardest part, IMO, of this problem is not confusing yourself.

Define $y = x^p - x$. So you are looking at the field $K = k(y)$. (or maybe use $\alpha$ instead of $y$ if you prefer)

$x$ is algebraic over $K$. Your goal is to find a polynomial over $K$ -- an element $f \in K[t]$ -- such that $f(x) = 0$.

So can you find a polynomial expression in $x$ with coefficients in $K$ that vanishes? If so, you can then write down an $f(t)$, that makes for a good starting point to begin solving the problem.

Comment: I understand that for $f(t)=t^p-t-y$ we have $f(0)=0$. But is there any usual way to check minimality.

Comment: @Hoseyn: (you mean we have $f(x) = 0$, since $f(0) = y$) In my opinion, the easiest way to approach the problem is probably to compute $[K:k]$ from the description of the two fields you already have.